# cannot get nodejs working on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am trying to run nodejs server on amazon micro instance for the past 3-4 days with no success.

i followed so many tutorials and i cannot make the server work (so when its visited in browser or curl in powerShell and see the simple hello world).

Here are the last 3 tutorials I've tried:

http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/
http://techprd.com/setup-node-js-web-server-on-amazon-ec2/
http://devblog.daniel.gs/2014/01/deploying-node-apps-on-aws-ec2-with.html

I've tried ubuntu/ amazon linux.

I've also followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html just to see how the general process works and it did work fine.

I get to the point where i do something like: `sudo node filename.js`
and the server runs.

However when i try visiting or curl it. it doesnt work. when i ping it it pings fine.

in amazon i set the security group to basically allow everything like so:

[image]

in linux its self i followed : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables to open the port i was trying to listen to and nothing.

when i type : `sudo service iptables status` i get :

`1 ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpts:1337:1347`

`2 ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpts:1338:1348`

`3 ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:10000`

keep in mind i am not a server savvy guy.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** To start my node server i use the basic code found in nodejs.org :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This is exactly how my file look like

Comment: What do you mean by `in amazon i set the security to basically allow everything`? What are the settings of the security group applied to that instance?

Comment: post update with how my security group look like

Comment: Can you curl localhost from that machine while the service is running? If no, then the service doesn't work. If yes, then the port may not be one of those listed.

Comment: Opened 2 terminal of putty, run node js on one, and type curl localhost:1337 on the other and got back hello world

Comment: Cool. What does "sudo iptables -L" report?

Comment: BTW i've added post with more details. sudo iptables -l reports: `ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:menandmice-dns:bbn-mmc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:wmc-log-svc:bbn-mmx
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ndmp
`

Comment: Not an iptables expert, but those look fine. Do you have outbound ALL allowed in that Security Group?

Comment: outbound is set to ALL yea. dont know how to deal with that. been at it for so long for something that seem so simple for others. i tried so many instance types ..

Comment: Thanks sallie i hope someone with more knowledge could shade some light

Comment: How do you start your node server?  What does your code for you listener look like?

Comment: I've update the post with the node js - its a very basic code though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't provided enough info, but I'll try and outline the general troubleshooting techniques.

- Is your node program running and serving requests?  Get on the Ec2 box and do `curl -v localhost:8000` (or whatever your node port is.) It should spit out your app. If not, your node.js setup isn't right.
- Is your nginx running? Get on the box and type `curl -v localhost`. That will look on your port 80. If it doesn't proxy to your app, it's probably an nginx configuration problem.
- Can you reach the box via IP address? From your desktop/laptop, do `curl -v x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is your EC2 Public IP address. If that hangs, there is a firewall problem.
- Can you reach the box via your DNS? (Assuming you are trying to have foo.com point to it) Try `curl -v http://foo.com/`. If that doesn't work, your DNS may not be correct.

> However when i try visiting or curl it. it doesnt work.

Please be more specific.

Comment: will answer your questions in the order you asked them: 1. curl -v localhost:8000 spits hello world. 2. did not set up nginx it had an issue however not sure how its relevant for what i am trying to do. 3. i tried both public ip and public DNS with port number and none do anything

Comment: by visit i mean in the browser by either using the public ip or public DNS with the port number,  when i try to curl from my pc with powerShell i getcurl -v localhost